# why putting \n alters the order of execution

Tags: c++, c, sleep, zombie-process

while I am trying to code in c for zombie process simulation ,I am getting alteration in output due to putting of \n in printf statements:

code1:

```
main()
{
 int id;
 id=fork();

 if(id>0)
  {
     printf("Parent will sleep");//pf1//
     sleep(5);
     //system("ps -u");
  }
 if(id==0)
     printf("I am child");//pf2//
}
```

output:

```
I am childParent will sleep
```

but while putting \n in pf1 or pf2 the order of execution of statements changes.what is the reason behind \n altering the order ?

Comment: the order isn't guaranteed, and can't be expected to be consistent

Comment: Are you using two programming languages at the same time?

Comment: i gave c++ as IMHO language is not the point here in this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`stdout` is *line-buffered*.

When you `printf` something to stdout, the library buffers this content up until a newline character is observed. At that point, the buffer is flushed, and will finally be displayed on your console. If you don't print a newline character, the data may stay in the buffer indefinitely, and you won't see it until the next time you print a newline character, or the process exits.

To ensure that your prints are always visible immediately, you can do one of these things:

- `fprintf(stderr, ...)` instead. `stderr` is not buffered; data written to it will be visible immediately.
- `fflush(stdout)` - Manually force the stream to be flushed immediately.

*Update:* Note that none of this actually matters, because of the inherent race condition involved. You have no control over whether the parent or child process executes first, and which one's data will be written to the console first. You could even possibly see the output interleaved as they both try to print at the same time. (*Thanks to jschultz410 for pointing out my foolishness.*)

Comment: What you said is true, but there are also inherent races in his code.  Even with line terminators he could easily see it print out in either order on different runs.

Comment: @jschultz410 Not with a `sleep(5)` present. Granted, it's still technically a race condition, but there's no way the scheduler isn't going to schedule the child for 5 seconds.

Comment: That wasn't my point. My point was that even if he adds \n to both his printf's he could easily see the print outs in either order.

Comment: @jschultz410 Wow. I looked at it three times and could've sworn the sleep was *before* the print (which would have "guaranteed" that the child printed first). So nevermind, you're absolutely correct.